How to read multiple CSV files and put them into separate Pandas dataframes?
I am trying to loop over a directory with multiple CSV files and read them into (separate) pandas dataframes.
I have tried several methods but I cannot manage to do so. However I did manage to read the CSV files and put them into a list. Yet, when trying to read a CSV file, my python does not find the file.
I have tried this code (I made an anonymous path) :
import pandas as pd 
        
import os

path = r'C:\path\UV' 



directory = os.fsencode(path)
lijst = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        #print(os.path.join(filename))
        lijst.append(file)
        #df = pd.read_csv(file)
        continue
    else:
        continue
lijst

for i in lijst:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

#pd.read_csv("UltraViolet1")

This gives an error, the code cannot read the files (they are named UltraViolet1 etc.)
Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

The issue seems to be that you are using filename instead of the full path to the file when trying to read into a dataframe. read_csv expects the full paths. Here's a fix:
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r'C:\path\UV'

dataframes = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        dataframes.append(df)

for df in dataframes:
       print(df.head()) 


Here's how to read multiple CSV files and put them into separate Pandas dataframes:
import pandas as pd
import os

data_dir = "path/to/your/csv/data"
dataframes = {}

for filename in os.listdir(data_dir):
  if filename.endswith(".csv"):
    filepath = os.path.join(data_dir, filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    dataframes[filename] = df

print(dataframes['file1.csv'].head())


Taking the clue from the OP,
import glob
import pandas as pd
names = glob.glob('C:/path/UV/*.csv') 
final_df=[]
for name in names:
  df = pd.read_csv(name)
  final_df.append(df) 
df_f=pd.concat(final_df, axis =0).reset_index() 

Hope this helps.

The problem here (probably) is that os.listdir only returns file names.  It does not return the actual path.  So, if you are running this from a directory OTHER than path, the files will not be found.
I suggest:
import glob
import pandas as pd
names = glob.glob('C:/path/UV/*.csv')
for name in names:
    df = pd.read_csv(name)

Note, however, that this keeps overwriting the df variable over and over.  You will probably want to save the dataframes in a list.
